# Auto refer to the components in the template?

Tags: html, angular6, components, angular-components

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. Is it possible to refer to a component (in this case, my `custom-component`) used in the template, like in this case:

```
<custom-component #select
   name="name1"
   title="Select first option"
   [(ngModel)]="select.value"

>
</custom-component>
```

As you can see, the `[(ngModel)]` propery has value `select.value`. This value is a property of the CustomComponent (that I **always** need to be connect to the ngModel). To refer to it, I used `#select`, but 
I would like to know if there are other ways or keywords that allow me to use the `value` property without using the `#select` decorator in every use of the custom component in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngModel` along with `ControlValueAccessor` on a custom component.

Inside the `custom-componen` class extend the `ControlValueAccessor`

```
export class CustomComponent implements  , ControlValueAccessor { 

    onChange = (val: string) => { };
    onTouched = () => { }; 

    writeValue(val: string): void { 
       // value passed from parent throug ngModel will come under this funtion
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (val: string) => void): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    } 

    ngOnInit() {
    } 

    // If you want to emit value to parent use the onChange function
    myEmitFunction(){
        this.onChange("value u want to emit")
    }
}
```